# Is there a list (or way to generate a list) of all the built-in SQL functions of Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking for a list (or way to generate a list) of all the built-in SQL functions of Snowflake, ideally in Backus-Naur Form. e.g.

- data type of function return value
- data types of its arguments
- semantics of the arguments, i.e. the argument names if defined in db
  documentation

I see the list on https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference-functions.html but I don't want to copy and paste from hundreds of pages on the help site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to generate list of all built-in functions using [SHOW FUNCTIONS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-functions.html):

```
SHOW FUNCTIONS;

SELECT "name", "arguments", "description"
FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))
WHERE "is_builtin" = 'Y';
```

Output:

[image]

EDIT:

It is possible to do it using single SHOW command:

```
SHOW BUILTIN FUNCTIONS;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We don't have as a list outside of docs, but it does make sense to have it and I would recommend you open an idea for it following:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Search-Create-Vote-Follow-Ideas

The more votes, the higher chance to get it.